# Write a C program to swap content of memory blocks of size 32 bytes

Tags: c, memory, swap

I have been given the following task:

> Write a C program to swap contents of memory blocks of size 32 bytes.

I don't have a clue of how pointer concept would be used to swap contents of size 32 bytes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) This question has nothing to do with compiler design. 2) We are not going to do your programming for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's similar to the way you can use a temporary variable to swap two integers:

```
int t = a;   // temporarily save a
a = b;       // overwrite a with b
b = t;       // overwrite b with saved a
```

In this case, you can create a temporary buffer of size 32 bytes with the following declaration:

```
char tempbuff[32];
```

and then use that to swap the contents of the two other 32-byte buffers, keeping in mind that `memcpy` can copy arbitrary chunks of memory, as with:

```
memcpy (tempbuff, firstbuff, 32); // copy firstbuff to tempbuff
```

That, combined with the earlier `int t = a; a = b; b = t;` method, should be *more* than enough to get you writing a complete program to do the job you need.